# Spring page redirection good habits

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm a beginner with Spring and I'm trying to understand how a controller works.
I have several methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` and everything works fine, but I don't know how to handle simple page requests.

Suppose I have to redirect from one page to another, without making server logic. If I create the url redirecting to `PageA.jsp` it seems that I always need to define the method catching the request in the Controller, declaring a method that is pratically empty, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/PageA.jsp")
public String redirectToPageA(){
return "PageA";
}
```

If I don't follow this approach I get 404 error as the controller can't find the mapping. I don't like this approach very much as it fills my controller with useless empty methods.

Which is the suggested approach?

Comment: No you don't you can use a [view-controller](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller) for that.

Comment: So, as far as I understand, you want to go to some `JSP` directly? Without of making URL mapping within controller which returns that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a [**view resolver**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html).

Read more about it [here - 17.5.1 Resolving views with the ViewResolver interface from 17. Web MVC framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver-resolver).

In that section you have

> As an example with JSP as a view technology, you can use the
>   UrlBasedViewResolver. This view resolver translates a view name to a
>   URL and hands the request over to the RequestDispatcher to render the
>   view
>
> ```
> <bean id="viewResolver"
>         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
>     <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
>     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
>     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
> </bean>
> ```
>
> When returning test as a logical view name, this view resolver
>   forwards the request to the RequestDispatcher that will send the
>   request to /WEB-INF/jsp/test.jsp. including the code.

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14427500/4807777) has the annotation based configuration of a view resolver (except you could use the UrlBasedViewResolver).

Comment: you can also try apache-tiles for template, and you can also have multiple view resolver with property order to load on priority. http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-tiles-example for tiles example